# Extracting ServerAlias to another file

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration, virtualhost

I have a virtual host file with a ServerAlias:

```
ServerName mydomain.net
ServerAlias myalias.net
ServerAlias *.mydomain.net
```

For some reason, we'd like to have the ServerAlias in a different file. I know that Apache can deal with virtual hosts in different files, but if I put just this in a file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mydomain.net
ServerAlias myalias.net
DocumentRoot "/www"
</VirtualHost>
```

Then the virtual host is incomplete, as well as duplicated. So is it possible to have just a directive in a separate file?

Comment: Have you tested an `Include` directive inside a `VirtualHost`?

Comment: @kasperd But that would have to go in the original file, wouldn't it? I can't add anything to the original file. Any change has to go in a separate file.